# Loop Include Statements

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, include

The problem is it won't loop.  There are multiple results and I just echo the results I get all of them.  When I use include, it only displays the first record. Can this be done.  I've tried for each, I've tried with array, I've tried just rolling through the results because I'm only grabbing one field, but it won't roll through all results, only the first one.  Thank you.

```
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);  
mysql_select_db($dbname); 
$sqlr = "select qNumber from regquestions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,5";
$query = mysql_query($sqlr); 
//$result = mysql_query($sqlr);
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
include ("q".$rows['qNumber'].".php");
}
```

using Echo I get this on the page:

```
q22.phpq3.phpq17.phpq13.phpq4.php
```

Using the include I get the first result which is to include one page, but I need it to include all of the pages.

Comment: there is a good chance your query didn't return anything, because the database connection failed

Comment: Why are you calling `mysql_query()` twice with the same query?

Comment: You're going to get some weird behavior here because you're using include inside of a loop.

Comment: Sorry, that extra $result line is in there.  I had it commented out trying another method

Comment: `The problem is it won't loop` Yes data may be empty

Comment: The database connection didn't fail.  I can do Echo ("q".$rows['qNumber'].".php"); and see all the results and as I said, using include I get only the first result. So there are results

Comment: As you say that only the first loop works it should have something wrong within the second file. Or the file doesnt exist at all. Have you set the php configurations to show all errors?

Comment: The files exist. I can manually code it like this: include 'q1.php';



include 'q2.php';



include 'q5.php';

etc. and it all displays fine. The intent was to randomize the test questions and not have to hard code every time I needed to change the test

Comment: Try `include ("'q".$rows['qNumber'].".php'");`

Comment: Try to use simple loop statement with `include`, you will see result.

Comment: @ling.s That won't work, it will try to find files with `'` in their names, which seems very unlikely.

Comment: If you change `include` to `require`, do you get errors?

Comment: @ling.s Close.  It's looping all results but it's not looking for them in the current directory, it's looking in the default include path...That's closer than it's been so far though

Comment: Try running it with
`while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo ("q".$rows['qNumber'].".php");
    echo '</br>';
}`

Comment: Also, it if ever pulls the same file twice, it will break.  You need to use `include_once("file.php");`

Comment: @w3rthl3ss Echo just prints the code on the page

Comment: Paste what it prints and what you're expecting it to print

Comment: `require __DIR__ . '/"q".$rows['qNumber'].".php"';`

Comment: @w3rthl3ss, see the edit above on the original post.  It shows what prints when I use echo.

Comment: If you put the `'</br>'`, it will show you how many times it loops, because you will have that many lines.  If you are saying your problem is it wont loop...

Comment: Also, `mysql_fetch_array` is deprecated.  You should use `mysqli_fetch_array` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: @w3rthl3ss No problem with `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: @ling.s Check the Manual.  Deprecated as of 5.5, it is not yet removed. - http://www.php.net/function.mysql-fetch-array

Comment: You can work with that, Thats not an issue here

Comment: Thank you everyone for the assistance and your responses.  The original code worked with a change of name or $query as it was conflicting with a variable of the same name in the include files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You say your loop ends after including first file, check if $rows variable being altered in this file (thus triggering the loop end). For example:

other.php:

```
$rows = 'just a check';
```

index.php:

```
$rows = 'somevalue';
include('other.php');
echo $rows; // output: just a check
```

2) change include to include_once just to be sure

Comment: No, the next file runs a query and outputs data. The variable in the include files is called $row  so it doesn't interfere with $rows in this one

Comment: Well, all possible loops provided, including yours, should work. Can you show the file you're including? Try including some test files with  just echo inside.

Comment: Thank you.  $Row/$Rows wasn't an issue but $query/$query in the current page and includes was.  I changed $query to $queries in the current file and all the includes now load and run their individual queries to populate the test questions and options.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
include ("'q".$rows['qNumber'].".php'");
```

The OP said It's looping all results but it's not looking for them in the current directory, it's looking in the default include path.

So, try this:

```
require __DIR__ . '/"q".$rows['qNumber'].".php"';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using assign a common page and send all requirements to that page functions

For eg:

```
include("repeat.php");
for($x=1;$x<10;$x++) 
{ 
echo div($x);
}
```

repeat.php

```
function div($x) {
    return "<div>$x</div>";
}
```

Or Try this type of includes

```
<?php
for($x=1;$x<10;$x++)
{
include('repeat2.php');
}  
?>
```

repeat2.php page

```
 <? //repeat2.php
echo "<div>$x: ".date('H:i:s')."</div>";
sleep(5);
?>
```

But the second one takes long time to load

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT qNumber FROM regquestions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,5;") or die(mysql_error());

for($i = 0; $array[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $i++);

// Delete last empty one
array_pop($array);

$x = 0;
$end_of_list = count($array)

while ($x < $end_of_list)
{
    include_once("q".$array[$x].".php");
    $x++;
}
```

Comment: I was hopeful with this but it stops after the first include